# How to find a cube root of numbers?

Tags: arithmetic, radicals

While, I was solving a problem of Chemistry [Solid State] when I encountered an equation like : $$a^3 = 3.612 \times 10^{-23} $$

Where, a is just a quantity [Actually, it is the length of a cubic unit cell.]

I was required to find the **cube-root** of $a^3$ as I had to use $a$ to find another quantity which was actually my answer.

I know that the cube-root of $a^3$ here can be found by using *logarithm.*

$$\begin{align} & \log{a^3} = \log{(3.612 \times 10^{-23})} \\
& 3\log{a} = \log{(36.12 \times 10^{-24})} \\
& 3\log{a} = \log{(36.12)} + \log{(10^{-24})} \\
& 3\log{a} = \log{(36.12)} - 24 \\
& \log{a} = \cfrac{\log{(36.12)} - 24}{3} \end{align} $$

By using logarithm table, I found $\log{(36.12)} = 1.557$

Now, just putting this : $$\begin{align} & \log{a}  = \cfrac{1.557 - 24}{3}  \\ & \\ & \log{a} = \cfrac{-22.443}{3} \end{align} $$

Now, taking antilog both sides, this becomes : $$a = antilog(-7.481) $$

Now, by using anti-log table, I got this as $$\boxed{a = 3.303 \times 10^{-8} } $$

Now, as you all might have noticed that this is a lot longer method and this has larger probability of a student doing a mistake in the calculations etc.

Is there a shorter or any proper method to find cube-root of a number like stated above?

Comment: To be honest, I really don't know that which tag will be the best for this question. If you have any ideas for proper tag for this, please feel free to add the tag by editing the post. Thanks!

Comment: From $a^3 = 36.12\cdot 10^{-24}$, you can go directly to $a = \sqrt[3]{36.12}\cdot 10^{-8}$, and getting the cube root of $36.12$ gives you a little less opportunity of screwing up.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Daniel for responding. Yes, that is what I thought to do but again, it will not be appropriate to just guess the cube root of 36.12 as in Chemistry, most of the times, it is required to get at least, the most possible accurate answer.

Comment: Even if we take the case that you suggested, how will we be going to find cube root of $36.12$ ? Obviously, without using any calculator.

Comment: Mr. Thomas, thanks for adding the tag - Teaching. I appreciate that.

Comment: Obviously, one would use a calculator of some sort, usually. Apart from that, you can get decent approximations without one by using a bit of calculus. $3^3 = 27$, and $36.12 = 27(1 + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{0.12}{27})$, and $\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{1}{3}}\approx 1 + \frac{1}{9}$.

Comment: It would help if you explained why a calculator or computer algebra system isn't used, or even google -- type "(3.612)((10^(-23))" in the search window and press Enter. I used logarithms for calculations like this when I was in high school, but that was 40 years ago. Are you simply interested in a method for finding cube roots by hand? If so, you can easily find this by going to google books and looking at digitized copies of 1800s books in arithmetic and algebra.

Comment: Mr. Daniel, how did you get to this : 

$$ 36.12 = 27 \left( 1 + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{0.12}{27} \right) $$ ?

Comment: I get the sense that OP is looking for an algorithm for calculating cube roots by hand.

Comment: Mr. Dave L. Renfro, thanks for responding. While, I understand what you mean but questions like this are 100% sure to come in my Exams, and I will not be allowed to use any type of computer or technology to find the cube root of such numbers. I'm not that interested in finding the cube root of such numbers by using tricks etc. In fact, I'm searching for a proper method to do this which can be used for all numbers.

Comment: See [p. 413](http://books.google.com/books?id=z_gSAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA413) of Gilbert A. Christian and George Collar's 1899 book [**A New Arithmetic, Theoretical and Practical**](http://books.google.com/books?id=z_gSAQAAMAAJ), for example.

Comment: Will you have the use of logarithm tables for your exams? If so, then that's the method you want to use. That's how calculuations like this were done in school and college science classes before calculators. Well, there were also slide rules, but they were less accurate unless the logarithm tables were very short.

Comment: Yes, I will be allowed to use logarithm tables in Exams. So, basically this is the only method I can use? :(

Comment: Yes, that's essentially the only method. It's actually not all that involved -- you only have to add/subtract a few decimal numbers and divide by the one-digit number $3.$ Methods for finding cube roots by hand (without logarithm tables) are WAY WAY more complicated, computational, and time-consuming.

Comment: I see. I think, I will have to become handy with using Logarithm method now. Thanks a lot Mr. Dave!

Comment: Out of curiosity, I looked at the reference (http://books.google.com/books?id=z_gSAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA413) in the prior comment, and I think the logarithm method seems faster and less error-prone; certainly it is more direct.

Comment: And a little humor on the same topic, from A Space Child's Mother Goose: "Little Jack Horner / Sits in a corner / Extracting cube roots to infinity ..." http://www.improbable.com/airchives/paperair/volume3/v3i5/mg35.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a log/antilog table and no calculator, your approach is probably optimal. Without such a table, I think you are better off proceeding as:

$$\left ( 3.612 \cdot 10^{-23} \right )^{1/3} \\
= \left ( 36.12 \cdot 10^{-24} \right )^{1/3} \\
= 36.12^{1/3} \cdot 10^{-8}$$

Then do bisection to find $36.12^{1/3}$. Note that $3^3=27<36.12$ and $4^3=64>36.12$. (If you can't find a small interval quickly, just use $[1,10]$.) So now you keep checking midpoints until you get your desired level of precision: $3.5^3 > 36.12$, $3.25^3<36.12$, $3.375^3>36.12$, etc. If at some point the arithmetic gets to be too messy, you can round, at the expense of some convergence speed. For example, you could check $3.4$ instead of $3.375$, then $3.4^3>36.12$, so you could check $3.3$. Then $3.3^3<36.12$, so you have $a=(3.35 \pm 0.05) \cdot 10^{-8}$.

You can also do Newton's method, which in this case is $x_{k+1} = \frac{2 x_k}{3} + \frac{c}{3 x_k^2}$ where you want $c^{1/3}$, but this is hard to do by hand, because the fractions quickly become very awkward, even with rounding.

Comment: With bisection, the final result is an interval $[a,b]$ where you know the root is located. Given this interval, the best single guess for the root is $(a+b)/2$, which is within $(b-a)/2$ of every point in $[a,b]$. So in my example, my final interval was $[3.3,3.4]$. That is, I know, from my procedure, that $36.12^{1/3}$ is between $3.3$ and $3.4$. Therefore the root is within $0.05$ of $3.35$.

Answer (score 2):

I think your method is probably the best way to solve for the cube root of a number.

I found some sites that offer quick solution towards finding a cube root, but they assume that your answer will be expressed as a whole number.

Link 1: https://www.math.hmc.edu/~benjamin/papers/Cubing.pdf

Link 2: http://www.careeranna.com/calculate-cube-roots-in-less-than-5-seconds/

Comment: @KushashwaRaviShrimali I'm actually very disappointed as well that there is no algorithm to find cube roots. Some sites only offer methods that only yield integer answers. I'll try and search online; I'm very intrigued to see how the algorithm will work.

Comment: @Varun Iyer: For an algorithm to find cube roots numerically, see my comments to the OP's question. Such algorithms are fairly common in really old textbooks, and I gave a link for one such textbook.